# PDF Analyser or repair tool

Tags: errors, pdf, conversion

I got one PDF that is resultant file after conversion and merging of 17 documents(few documents were already converted to PDF) however resultant file has been converted and merged using activePDF.

Now for resultant PDF file I am getting two errors when I open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader x I also tried Adobe Acrobat Prof latest to analyse but nothing helped, can someone guide me in right direction please

> "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
>   correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to
>   correct the problem."

and

> "Cannot extract the embedded font "HiddenHorzOCR". Some characters may
>   not display or print correctly."

Both errors are coming up for same document.

**Main Problem**

Converted/Merged PDF got invisible text for a specific PDF document, when I open open on its own, everything works fine.

I guess If I embedded that font into resultant document might solve problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Try ghostscript, it works most of the time for me.

Comment: This does not really appear to be a TeX question. Wouldn't that be better on the main page?

Comment: This question seems to be out of topic. Please rephrase it to show how this is linked to a LaTeX, ConText or TeX.

Comment: I have been recommended to use this forum on meta, and it got tags for "PDF" and "Conversion" so how is it out of topic :S

Comment: @JuriRobl how can I use ghostscript, I am going to google it tho

Comment: @Sveinung: I guess that depends on how the documents were merged. If each of the documents were ok individually, and were merged using the LaTeX tools, and then when put together they were no longer ok, then it would be on topic.  So, we need information on exactly how the documents were actually merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) you can concatenate PDF documents. I guess once the document is broken, fixing it becomes really hard. You can use pdftk to decompress it, so you can edit it as text, but this is a lot of hard-to-understand text, so I'd advise in not breaking the file in the first place.